# Need advice on 301 redirect from hyphenated domain to

Tags: domains, google-search, 301-redirect

I have been an online service since 2005 and have gained some good ranking on Google and other search engines.

My domain name is for example is: www.smart-service.co.uk.

I have recently got hold of www.smartservice.co.uk (example) and would prefer this domain as it looks a lot cleaner, more professional and less spammy.

The website itself is professional and has many corporate customers and I feel the non-hyphenated name would look like we are more serious and not doing business by accident on a second choice domain. The domain has PR6 and Domain Authority of 70.

I have read up a lot about doing 301 redirects but everyone has different opinions on whether it hurts rankings much or not. At the same time I feel I have a lot to gain switching over and would don't want to invest more money on SEO on the hyphenated domain if I end up doing it in future.

Also another thing to note is that the hyphon domain age is 8 years whilst the non-hyphon is only 4 years, does this matter?

It's a bit of a dilemma and wish to have some other opinions on what I should do.

Thanks!
Aki

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply 301 redirect from www.smart-service.co.uk to www.smartservice.co.uk without SEO problems.

In your case, domains age doesn't really matter; 301 redirect explains to Google the domain has changed and it's almost always the case where old domain (by age) is redirected to new domain (by age).

In order to keep your PR, make sure all your old URLs are redirected to new ones. Be careful of duplicate content.